# Display a number value from mysql query in WP

Tags: plugins, mysql, sql

Anyone have a suggestion on how I can display the result of a SQL query in a WP post or page? The query statement is a SUM statement and I want to only display the resulting number value on the page. An example would be the number of pizza's sold etc.

Comment: I don't see any code in your question, what have you tried so far? Which parts elude you?

Comment: Thank you there is no code sine I dont know where to start. I know all the sql code that I need and I know syntax is valid. It is a question of how I display that in a wordpress site that eludes me?

Comment: So you don't know how to execute the SQL query? Or you do know how to execute it but aren't sure how to put it in a post? There's at least 2 large questions in here, you'd be better off asking them separately, how to embed something in a post, and how to execute your query

Comment: Good on the query and statement thank you. I dont know how to display (embed) that in wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Your easiest route to this is probably shortcodes, which effectively allow you to insert the output from a bit of PHP code in a post or page.

For example, this would create the shortcode `[countpeople]` which you could pop in any post and it would render the value from the SQL statement using a `$wpdb` helper function:

```
function my_plugin_name_count_people() {
    global $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PEOPLE;");
}

add_shortcode('countpeople', 'my_plugin_name_count_people');
```

Read more about shortcodes here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Comment: Thank you very much!